# How to install this package?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, i3-wm

I would like to install: [i3blocks](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=i3blocks).

But when I try: `sudo apt-get install i3blocks` I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package i3blocks
```

How to fix this?

p.s.: I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: according to the link you posted, the package is only available for Ubuntu versions >= 15.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the link you provided, package `i3blocks` is **not available** for 14.04 (trusty), only for vivid (15.04), wily (15.10) and the next release vivid (16.04). There are also no backports available.

Installing the package for one of the later Ubuntu releases is generally not recomended, as it may break your package db and prevent you from installing other packages or upgrading your currently installed ones.

Comment: Oh, what can be done then?

Comment: It depends on how badly you need this program. You could upgrade your Ubuntu to a newer release (15.10 is the current development release, and 16.04 is not yet beta, so not recommended for general usage), or search for a PPA containg a backported version.

I couldn't find one with a quick search, but that doesn't mean one doesn't exist. I'm sorry that's not the answer you wanted, but this is the possible answer to your question.

Comment: @Inspired_Blue The release of ubuntu 16.04 LTS is scheduled for April 21st, 2016. I would probably wait until then and upgrade the system. Note that you cannot upgrade directly from 14.04 to 15.10. You'd need to upgrade to 15.04 first, so you will need *two* upgrades to get to 15.10. However, a direct upgrade from one LTS version (14.04) to the next one (16.04) is possible.

Comment: Well, one can follow the instructions here and make their own copy: https://github.com/vivien/i3blocks

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to wait until 16.04 is released you can clone this repo: https://github.com/vivien/i3blocks and build it yourself. Look at the documentation if you don't know how to get it built.

This guide here was helpful when I went that route: http://kumarcode.com/Colorful-i3/, however, you are going to have to tweak a few things to get it working. The scripts and icons that he provides are pretty useful.